# Eliminate entering QR - Whatsapp web automated by selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, local-storage, whatsapp

I'm trying to eliminate the process of the QR code after the **first** I'm doing it.

My code to run Whatsapp trough a web driver:

```
public class DriverTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
    ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\whatsup\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe"))
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .build();

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.merge(capabilities);
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);

    driver.navigate().to("https://web.whatsapp.com/");

    while (driver.findElements(By.xpath(XPaths.autoStartReady)).size() == 0);

    LocalStorage localStorage = driver.getLocalStorage();

    driver.close();

    driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);

    for (String key : localStorage.keySet()){
        String value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        driver.executeScript("window.localStorage.setItem('"+key+"', '"+value+"');");
    }

    driver.navigate().to("https://web.whatsapp.com/");

}
```

}

When the web browser opens for the first time, I'm doing the QR code routine on my phone. The exception was raised while executing the javascript code.

But I'm getting the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
```

If I'm trying to save the cookies, the cookies set is empty (cannot save any cookie, still don't know why).

How can I skip this process of the QR after the first time? If someone knows how to skip it without even doing it once, it will be also helpful (but I think too much difficult for now).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: faced with same issue, please post if you have found a solution

Comment: @DebanjanB Do you have any idea on this, we have been waiting for a answer on this for some time.

Answer (score 15):

Use profiles!

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=D:\Python\Memory\WebWhatsAppBot")

navegador = webdriver.Chrome(
executable_path="D:\Python\WebWhatsAppBot\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
navegador.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution?

Comment: Yep, profile is the right way to bypass QR code scanning each time. You just need to scan ones. I have also used profile

Answer (score 5):

Marcelo's answer is correct but poorly explained in my opinion, so here's what worked for me:

Create a folder in your project directory to store all the cache that the chromedriver session will create (it's also nice to ignore the content in your `.gitignore` file).

[image]

And then, start the webdriver options and set the directory.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=./driver/data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./driver/chromedrive84_win', options=options)
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the qr code scaning after first attemp if you have not use

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito"); 
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
```

after removing --incognito type option